# How to calculate luminance, given a light source's luminous intensity?

Tags: optics, visible-light, light-emitting-diodes, luminosity

For example, let's suppose I have $2.5$ mm diameter LED with a diffuse lens; it has luminous intensity of $2.0$ cd. Let's say it has viewing angle of 120 degrees and I'm viewing it head on. How would I calculate luminance for this LED? Do I need additional information for the calculation (if so, what are they typically using when advertising nits for TV/computer displays)?

I'm reading the definitions on Wikipedia and elsewhere, but nobody gives example calculations for real world lights, so I'm having trouble understanding what luminance is supposed to represent. It is luminous intensity per unit area, but what "unit area" is used as a reference? My guess is you take the cross-sectional area of the light source from your viewing angle, in this case a $2.5$mm diameter circle, or $4.91 \times 10^{-6} m^2$. That would give you $407437$ nits, which seems incredible high, given computer screens are typically ~$250$ nits.

Comment: Can you outline your math/calculations more concretely, to show how you got to 407437 $cd/m^2$?  It may help when trying to show where a calculation (or an assumption used as an input to the calculation) has gone wrong.  Also: it's not enough information to just say an LED "has luminous intensity of 2.0 cd".  Usually intensity is provided as a graph of intensity vs angle, not just a single number.  Is it uniformly 2.0 cd for all solid angles in that 120 degree cone?  Or are you saying we should just assume that the average intensity across a solid angle of interest is 2.0 cd?

Comment: Simply $(2.0\ cd) / (0.00125^2\pi\ m^2)$. That gives you the right units, but as I mentioned I am not clear whether that is the area you are supposed to divide by. $2.0\ cd$ is the peak at $0$ degrees. It's got a circular arc-like radiation falloff to 50% intensity at $120$ degrees. Seems even if you consider the min intensity in that viewing angle, it would still be very high result.